# How does the Decorator pattern chain method calls?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I read one example of Decorator Design Pattern. I understood that this design pattern modifies the behaviour of one particular instance dynamically. The example which I have given below is also understandable. The point which I did not understand is that when I call `c.getCost()` on a milk object, it returns 1.5.
Only `Simplecoffee`'s `getCost()` returns 1, but from where does `c.getCost` on milk return 1.5?

Can anyone please explain the link between the `Milk` class and `Simplecoffee` class, and how the execution of method `getCost()` flows when called with the milk object? How does the `getCost()` method return 1.5?

```
//Decorator Design Pattern
interface Coffee {
    public double getCost();

    public String getIngredients();
}

class Simplecoffee implements Coffee {
    public double getCost() {
        return 1;
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return "Coffee";
    }
}

abstract class CoffeeDecorator implements Coffee {
    protected Coffee decoratedcoffee;
    protected String ingredientseparator = ":";

    public CoffeeDecorator(Coffee decoratedcoffee) {

        this.decoratedcoffee = decoratedcoffee;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return decoratedcoffee.getCost();
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return decoratedcoffee.getIngredients();
    }
}

class Milk extends CoffeeDecorator {

    public Milk(Coffee decoratedcoffee) {

        super(decoratedcoffee);
        System.out.println("Milk Constructor");
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return super.getCost() + 0.5;
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return super.getIngredients() + ingredientseparator + "milk";
    }
}

public class Decorator {    
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        System.out.println("calling simplecoffee in main");
        Coffee c = new Simplecoffee();
        System.out.println("Cost:" + c.getCost());
        c = new Milk(c);
        System.out.println("Cost:" + c.getCost());
    }    
}
```

Comment: You could insert a `Thread.dumpStack()` in the `getCost` method of `Simplecoffee` to find out.

Comment: Basically, when you said c = new Milk(c) you are calling through inheritance the CoffeeDecorator constructor, which sets the SimpleCoffee instance as it's field (referenced via Interface Coffee), and the call to decoratedcoffee.getCost(); goes through inheritance to it's parent method which returns 1 and adds 0.5

Comment: "How the method ... flows when called with the milk object"  LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How the getCost() method returns 1.5 ?

The `getCost()` method in `Milk` first calls the `getCost` method on `decoratedcoffee` which is a reference to `SimpleCoffee`. This will therefore call the `getCost` method from `SimpleCoffee` which returns 1 (read : runtime polymorphism). Next, the `getCost` method in `Milk` adds the return value of this call (i.e 1) to `0.5` thus giving you the result as `1.5`

This is the whole point of the *Decorator* pattern. The *Decorator* is used for creating a chain of method calls by wrapping a new object into the existing chain.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look and understand this piece of code:

```
coffee c = new simplecoffee();
System.out.println("Cost:" + c.getCost());
```

- Create a **simplecoffee** object and assign it to `c`.
- `c` is declared to type **coffee** (no problem, since **simplecoffee** is an implementation of **coffee** interface).

Next step:

```
c = new milk(c);
System.out.println("Cost:" + c.getCost());
```

- Create a **milk** object and assign `c` to the new **milk** object (overwrite the old value of `c`).
- **milk** extends an abstract class `coffeedecorator` which also implements **coffee** Interface.
- The **simplecoffee** object from above is assigned to an instance variable inside of **milk** class.

Consider the implementation of **milk.getCost()** which is called before the last print:

```
    public double getCost(){

       return super.getCost() + 0.5;
    }
```

- `super.getCost()` is implemented in the **coffeedecorator** class. It simply calls the `getCost()` method of the **coffee** instance inside.
- In our case it is **simplecoffee** which costs 1.
- The milk costs 0.5.

So you get together 1.5.

Greets Alan.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather name your Milk class as MilkedCoffee. A decorator adds more features to original object by wrapping it, on the same time belong to same interface of the original object , so that your client code can work on it without knowing if it is coffee (original class ) or milkedcoffee ( decorator) or iced coffee ( another decorator). So the decorated coffee in your example should be a coffee , not an add on to coffee such as milk , sugar .. Etc

To answer your original question, the return value 1.5 looks fine if your logic is to add .5 cost when a coffee is served with milk ( in other words decorated as MilkedCoffee)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please explain the link between the Milk class and Simplecoffee class and how the execution of method getCost() flows when called with milk object. How does the getCost() method return 1.5?

It's hard to do better than the [visualization of the Decorator calls in Head First Design Patterns](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/Images/bc_images/hfdp_bc_web.jpg). Follow the green arrows below. The calls to `getCost()` are nested, and the return values are also shown in green. The image also shows how `Milk` *wraps* the `Simplecoffee` class.

[image]